# Python regex accept all characters except <>%;$

Tags: python, regex

I want to allow any character except `<>%;$`

What I have done is `r'^[^<>%;$]'` but it seems not working.

Comment: Please post relevant code. Even better put  a running example on ideone.com or codepad.org and share the link here.

Answer (score 4):

```
r'^[^<>%;$]+$'
```

You missed the quantifier `* or +`.

Answer (score 0):

The `r'^[^<>%;$]'` regex only checks for the characters other than `<`, `>`, `%`, `;`, `$` **at the beginning of the string** because of `^` anchor (asserting the position at the beginning of the string.

You can use Python `re.search` to check if a string contains any of these characters with a character class `[<>%;$]` or you can define a `set` of these characters and use `any()`:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'[<>%;$]') # Regex matching the specific characters
chars = set('<>%;$')       # Define the set of chars to check for

def checkString(s):
    if any((c in chars) for c in s): # If we found the characters in the string
        return False                 # It is invalid, return FALSE
    else:                            # Else
        return True                  # It is valid, return TRUE

def checkString2(s):
    if r.search(s):   # If we found the "bad" symbols
        return False  # Return FALSE
    else:             # Else
        return True   #  Return TRUE

s = 'My bad <string>'
print(checkString(s))   # => False
print(checkString2(s))  # => False
s = 'My good string'
print(checkString(s))   # => True
print(checkString2(s))  # => True
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/rdwihO)